# How do I show the table names that exist in a Java SQLite3 database?

Tags: java, sqlite

In the spirit of test-driven design I want to test whether the tables get properly created in my SQLite3 database. For that purpose I want to list the table names via an SQL query.

I created the tables with:

```
public static void setupTables(){
    try(Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
        String sql_student = ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + STUDENT_TABLE + "(\n "
                + ID + " integer PRIMARY KEY,\n "
                + FIRSTNAME + " text,\n "
                + LASTNAME + " text\n"
                + ");");
        String sql_teacher = ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TEACHER_TABLE + "(\n "
                + ID + " integer PRIMARY KEY,\n "
                + FIRSTNAME + " text,\n "
                + LASTNAME + " text\n"
                + ");");

        stmt.execute(sql_student);
        stmt.execute(sql_teacher);

        stmt.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What's the query I need for my test? Do I need to be concerned about order, or does the order in which the tables get created gurantee that they will always stored in the same order?

Answer (score 1):

1) `ATTACH mydb.db as my_db`
2) `SELECT name FROM my_db.sqlite_master where type='table';`
3) For temporary tables: `SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master WHERE type='table';`

Hope it will help!

Comment: Is there a reason the ATTACH is needed? It sounds to me like it results in the database to have to be a file and that it won't work with an in-memory database.

Comment: Only if you don't already have your database attached. If you don't have it attached, then the helper functions from .tables and .schema will query the SQLITE_MASTER table for the main database.

Comment: I would expect that a connection that I open in Java is specific to a certain database and that I have multiple connection options if I have multiple databases. Is there a good reason for structuring things in Java in a way where you always use attach?

Comment: I don't think that every SQLConnection that you've opened in java it's not attached to the correct database. So, I think that you can skip the first step.

Comment: Why did you downvoted me?

Comment: I didn't. I think it's most likely that CL cast that vote.

Comment: Can you please upvote me? Or i delete the answer...